# Magento form Validation with bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, magento

Magento add to cart having select box of options with required options is not working when bootstrap 3 is used. It simply does not validate the required field.
    
    //

```
            if (url) {
               form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

    productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
        if(this.validator) {
            var nv = Validation.methods;
            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
            // Remove custom datetime validators
            for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                    delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                }
            }

            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                if (url) {
                    this.form.action = url;
                }
                this.form.submit();
            }
            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
//]]>
</script>
```

the above script onclick is skipped on clicking on add to cart.

```
 Add to Cart
```

any guides pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to fix it myself, I have disabled the bootstrap.select.js and validation started to work